# Using two files to replace text in another file with bat?

Tags: batch-file, text, replace

I have a bit of snag trying to do something for the community I'm spending my time with and I require help. I am new with .bat and all.

I have 3 files.

1) A file with a list of IDs
2) A file with a list of Proper Names for the IDs
3) A file with a bunch of text and contains ID's randomly in it all over the place.

I would like to use the ID, and the Names to replace the ID inside the third file. The first and second file looks like:

```
ID.txt
======
001_Blue019
002_Bluer11
003_Buster142

Name.txt
======
Bob Blue
Bluer Baxster
Buster Arnold
```

Everything is perfectly aligned on it's proper line. I would like to use these two files to change a third file containing IDs randomly placed all over the text file, some IDs may appear more than once. I am having trouble with it, how do I accomplish this?

The third file looks like so, but has like over 500 different id appearing more than once:

```
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
002_Bluer11
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
003_Buster142
```

The final output or change should look like

```
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Bluer Baxster
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Buster Arnold
```

Comment: Please show a representative sample of the third file and show what you expect from processing the third file in the light of the other 2. I take it from your description that file1 has IDs and the name from the corresponding line from file2 is the actual name o be substituted for the ID wherever that ID occurs in file3. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. ID.txt and Name.txt has their corresponding text on the exact line number. Data.txt has a bunch ID strings all over the area, we just need these ones translated into names.

Comment: Okay I changed the main post to match the criteria you've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: load $*=IDs, #*=names
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364u.txt') DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364n.txt') DO SET "#%%a=%%b"&SET /a count+=1
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27679364d.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :process
)
)>"newfile.txt"

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,%count%) DO CALL :SUBST "%%$%%i%%" "%%#%%i%%"
ECHO(%line%
GOTO :eof

:SUBST
CALL SET "line=%%line:%~1=%~2%%
GOTO :eof
```

I used file named `q27679364u.txt` containing your ID data and `q27679364n.txt` your name data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

With this input data in file `q27679364d.txt`:

```
substitute here: 001_Blue019
nothing to substitute
what about this? 002_Bluer11 and 003_Buster142 and 001_Blue019
--- now your data ----
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
002_Bluer11
001_Blue019
001_Blue019
003_Buster142
```

(I made up my own data file while I was waiting; then added your data at the end)

The result was:

```
substitute here: Bob Blue
nothing to substitute
what about this? Bluer Baxster and Buster Arnold and Bob Blue
--- now your data ----
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Bluer Baxster
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Buster Arnold
```

which appeared in `newfile.txt`

---

Addendum.

Batch isn't known for its speed, but a great amount can be done by tuning the routine, especially in the light of the characteristics of the data being processed.

I extended the number of lines in the data file to more than 10,000 by mass-duplication of OP's data and measured the above process. On my machine it took 176 seconds (actual time would depend on machine characteristics and size of each file.)

I then modified the routine, assuming that the data in the third file contained **only** lines from the ID file, in random order and possibly duplicated.

This result:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: load $*=IDs, #*=names
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364u.txt') DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364n.txt') DO SET "#%%a=%%b"&SET /a count+=1
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27679364d.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=$=" %%i IN ('set $') DO IF /i "%%j"=="%%a" ECHO !#%%i!
)
)>"newfile.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

ran in 109 seconds - a useful saving.

So I thought further. Using the same data, I developed this:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $ or # or _
For %%b IN ($ # _) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: load $*=IDs, #*=names
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364u.txt') DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q27679364n.txt') DO SET "#%%a=%%b"&SET /a count+=1
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO SET "_!$%%a!=!#%%a!"&SET "$%%a="&SET "#%%a="
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27679364d.txt) DO (ECHO !_%%a!
)
)>"newfile.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Same resultant file, and it assumes that the IDs and names are all made from "nice characters" - those that have no meaning to `CMD`'s parser ie. The alphabet (upper and lower case) and numerics and also the set `[@#$+_-{}:.]` Note this very explicitly excludes <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and comma and also that batch rarely makes a distinction about case....

Oh - run-time, you ask?

Er, 0.63 sec.

Comment: this is exactly the solution I needed Magoo. The .bat is pretty slow at at converting it, but it works wonders. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your 3rd file consists of nothing but IDs, as shown in your example, then the following batch script should be quite fast:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Load the list of IDs
set "find="
<name.txt ( for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("id.txt") do (
  set "name="
  set /p "name="
  set "_%%A=!name!"
))

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("test.txt") do echo(!_%%A!
```

If the IDs in the 3rd file are mixed with other text, then I have a different fast solution that works as long as you have no more than four or five hundred ID/Name pairs. It uses [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Load the list of IDs
set "find="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("id.txt")   do set "find=!find!|%%A"
set find

:: Load the list of Names
set "repl="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("name.txt") do set "repl=!repl!|%%A"
set repl

:: Substitute Names for all IDs within test.txt and write the result to out.txt
call jrepl find repl /l /t "|" /v /f test.txt /o out.txt
```

Comment: I had about a little over 500 pairs of Id and names yes. Also needed to keep the other original texts part of it.